# Changing startIndent in Material3 Divider

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

In *androidx.compose.material* the Divider component is defined as:

```
@Composable
fun Divider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = DividerAlpha),
    thickness: Dp = 1.dp,
    startIndent: Dp = 0.dp
): Unit
```

In *androidx.compose.material3* the Divider component is defined as:

```
@Composable
fun Divider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    thickness: Dp = DividerDefaults.Thickness,
    color: Color = DividerDefaults.color
): Unit
```

How can we change startIndent in the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `startIndent` is a simple start offset achieved with `Modifier.padding(start = startIndent)`.

You can simply apply a `padding` modifier:

```
androidx.compose.material3.Divider(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Divider` is simply a `Box` with some modifiers.

You can create your own `Divider` which is similar as divider provided by material:

```
@Composable
fun CustomDivider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    thickness: Dp = DividerDefaults.Thickness,
    color: Color = DividerDefaults.color,
    startIndent: Dp = 0.dp,
) {
    val targetThickness = if (thickness == Dp.Hairline) {
        (1f / LocalDensity.current.density).dp
    } else {
        thickness
    }
    Box(
        modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = startIndent)
            .height(targetThickness)
            .background(color = color)
    )
}
```